# Golf return output logic issue

Tags: java, logic

Hey guys so I am trying to do a HW question for a java class and I am having some trouble understanding the logic. This is the question they asked of me:

*Golf scores record the number of strokes used to get the ball in the hole. The expected number of strokes varies from hole to hole and is called par (i.e. 3, 4 or 5). Each score has a cute name based on the actual strokes taken compared to par. Return "Eagle" if strokes is two less than par. Return "Birdie" if strokes is one less than par. Return "Par" if par matches strokes exactly. Return "Bogey" if strokes is one more than par. Return "Error" if par is not 3, 4 or 5.*

This is my code:

```
public class Main {
   
   public String golfScore(int par, int strokes){
      
      if(strokes <= par - 2){
         return "Eagle";
      }
      else if(strokes <= par -1){
         return "Birdie";
      }
      else if(strokes == par){
         return "Par";
      }
      else if(strokes > par + 1){
         return "Bogey";
      }
      else{
         return "Error";
      }
   }
   
   // this method not used but needed for testing
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   }
}
```

[When I run the results I get correct for everything except for the last test.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB8Ox.png)

But this logic doesn't make sense to me cause it should be invalidating my if statement. Cause 1 > 2 + 1 is false therefore it should be outputting an error. Why is my program outputting bogey?

Comment: `strokes > par + 1` you probably want `strokes > par `

Comment: It looks like there's specific logic for when Error _should_ be returned that doesn't appear to be handled in this logic

Comment: @Berto99 I tried it that way at first but then my other test case wasn't validating.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Okay I think you were right I did it like this and all my test cases passed! :)

`if ((par != 3) && (par != 4) && (par != 5)){
         return "Error";
      }
      else if(strokes <= par - 2){
         return "Eagle";
      }
      else if(strokes <= par -1){
         return "Birdie";
      }
      else if(strokes == par){
         return "Par";
      }
      else{
         return "Bogey";
      } 
   }`

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! Thanks to ChrisForrence!

```
if ((par != 3) && (par != 4) && (par != 5)){
     return "Error";
  }
  else if(strokes <= par - 2){
     return "Eagle";
  }
  else if(strokes <= par -1){
     return "Birdie";
  }
  else if(strokes == par){
     return "Par";
  }
  else{
     return "Bogey";
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was looking for the solution for this problem but written in C++, here it is.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int par;
    int strokes;

    cin >> par >> strokes;

    if ((par != 3) && (par != 4) && (par != 5)){
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
    else if (strokes == par - 2){
        cout << "Eagle" << endl;
    }
    else if (strokes == par - 1){
        cout << "Birdie" << endl;
    }
    else if (strokes == par){
        cout << "Par" << endl;
    }
    else if (strokes == par + 1){
        cout << "Bogey" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "None" << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```